# Try to write an excel sheet

Tags: python, excel, xlsx

I'm trying to write these cookie sales into an excel sheet, but I'm getting the "invalid syntax" error. Any thoughts on how to do this properly? Here is my code:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('hello2.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

cookie_sales = {
['Name': 'Sue', 'Feeny', 'Jimmy', 'Seymour'. 'Shawn', 'Corey', 'Anne', 'Terry', 'Derek', 'Sammy', 'Topanga', 'Alan', 'Mark', 'Joe', 'Elliot' ],
['Age':  23, 99, 23, 11, 31, 55, 35, 44, 71, 41, 39, 22, 16, 25, 32 ],
['Boxes_Sold':  5234, 5000, 4566, 3344, 3123, 534, 335, 654, 7773, 990, 11, 46, 742, 222, 9],
['Flavor': 'Chocolate', 'Cookie Dough', 'Cookie Dough', 'Mint', 'Vanilla', 'Chocolate', 'Vanilla', 'Strawberry', 'Strawberry', 'Vanilla', 'Mint', 'Strawberry', 'Chocolate', 'Chocolate' 'Mint' ],
}

row = 0
col = 0

for name, age, boxes_sold, flavor in (cookie_sales):
worksheet.write(row, col,     name)
worksheet.write(row, col + 1, age)
worksheet.write(row, col + 2, boxes_sold)
worksheet.write(row, col + 3, flavor)
row += 1


workbook.close()
```

Comment: I see you have a COMMA after mint , I think inizialization is not ok .

Comment: I got rid of the comma, but still doesn't work.

Comment: also a `.` after `Seymour`

Comment: Got rid of the period. Still no luck.

Comment: Also your dictionary syntax isn't quite right - you want to define `key` / `value` pairs like so:  `cookie_sales = {
'Name': ('Sue', 'Feeny', 'Jimmy', 'Seymour', 'Shawn', 'Corey', 'Anne', 'Terry', 'Derek', 'Sammy', 'Topanga', 'Alan', 'Mark', 'Joe', 'Elliot'),...`

Comment: I suggest you start with a simple matrix then use final example .

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: try ti start with a 2 3 columns XLS to reduce variables on error cases

Comment: Also, once you get the structure of your `cookie_sales` object worked out, might I suggest writing to .csv with `Pandas`: 
`import pandas as pd`
`pd.DataFrame(cookie_sales).to_csv("result.csv", index = False)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure if you're really going for a dictionary here or a list.
Changing it all to lists, this should yield the results you're looking for:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('hello2.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

cookie_sales = [
['Name', 'Sue', 'Feeny', 'Jimmy', 'Seymour', 'Shawn', 'Corey', 'Anne', 'Terry', 'Derek', 'Sammy', 'Topanga', 'Alan', 'Mark', 'Joe', 'Elliot' ],
['Age', 23, 99, 23, 11, 31, 55, 35, 44, 71, 41, 39, 22, 16, 25, 32],
['Boxes_Sold', 5234, 5000, 4566, 3344, 3123, 534, 335, 654, 7773, 990, 11, 46, 742, 222, 9],
['Flavor', 'Chocolate', 'Cookie Dough', 'Cookie Dough', 'Mint', 'Vanilla', 'Chocolate', 'Vanilla', 'Strawberry', 'Strawberry', 'Vanilla', 'Mint', 'Strawberry', 'Chocolate', 'Chocolate', 'Mint' ]]

row = 0
col = 0

for name in cookie_sales[0]:
    worksheet.write(row, col, name)
    worksheet.write(row, col + 1, cookie_sales[1][row])
    worksheet.write(row, col + 2, cookie_sales[2][row])
    worksheet.write(row, col + 3, cookie_sales[3][row])
    row += 1


workbook.close()
```

If you're curious about dictionaries, to do it using a dictionary, this would work as well, using your current structure:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('hello1.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

cookie_sales = {
'Name' : ['Sue', 'Feeny', 'Jimmy', 'Seymour', 'Shawn', 'Corey', 'Anne', 'Terry', 'Derek', 'Sammy', 'Topanga', 'Alan', 'Mark', 'Joe', 'Elliot' ],
'Age' : [23, 99, 23, 11, 31, 55, 35, 44, 71, 41, 39, 22, 16, 25, 32],
'Boxes_Sold' : [5234, 5000, 4566, 3344, 3123, 534, 335, 654, 7773, 990, 11, 46, 742, 222, 9],
'Flavor' : ['Chocolate', 'Cookie Dough', 'Cookie Dough', 'Mint', 'Vanilla', 'Chocolate', 'Vanilla', 'Strawberry', 'Strawberry', 'Vanilla', 'Mint', 'Strawberry', 'Chocolate', 'Chocolate', 'Mint' ]}

row = 0
col = 0

for key in cookie_sales.keys():
    worksheet.write(0, col, key) # Writes Heading
    row = 1
    for item in cookie_sales[key]: # Writes Heading contents
        worksheet.write(row, col, item)
        row += 1
    col += 1

workbook.close()
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Dictionary object needs to be structured as 
{key:value,key:value} but what you have is {key:value,value,value...}

The value can be a list or other data structure e.g
{key : (value1,value2,value3)}

which can be accessed with syntax cookie_sales['name'][i]

you may also need to restructure the loop.